# Video seek not working in vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder

Tags: vue.js, video, electron, electron-builder, seek

I am trying to add a simple HTML5  player that loads a local mp4 file. I've added the stream: true in background.js. The video loads but the seek is not working.

It seems it's just working in serve mode but not in the build. As a difference I have noticed the server answer on serve is "206" and on build is "200".

Any idea how to make the seeking to work?

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: I'm adding the video in the HelloWorld.vue file, it's just <video controls src="../assets/video.webm" />

The steps I followed:
vue create project;
vue add electron-builder;
edited src/background.js to add stream: true